# How can I print a '/' at a specific index in my matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I am trying to add and element at a specific index.

My output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I am expecting an output that prints a '/' at an index position of matrix[5][5] like below-

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 / 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The code I wrote is-

```
R = 10  #int(input("Enter the number of rows:")) 
C = 10 #int(input("Enter the number of columns:"))   
# Initialize matrix 
matrix = [] 
print("Enter the entries rowwise:") 
  
# For user input 
for i in range(R):          # A for loop for row entries 
    a =[] 
    for j in range(C):      # A for loop for column entries 
         a.append(0) 
    matrix.append(a)  
#print("/",matrix[index[20]][index[10]])
#matrix.insert([0][0],'/')
for i in range(R): 
    for j in range(C): 
        print(matrix[i][j], end = " ") 
    print()
```

I tried-

```
matrix.insert([0][0],'/')
```

But this caused an error as-

```
shubham@IAMSB:~$ python3 final.py
Enter the entries rowwise:
/ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(matrix[i][j], end = " ") 
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Please forgive my mistakes I new to PYTHON
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: simply matrix[5][5] = '/' will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is you can have an `if` condition when you are populating the list.

```
In [156]: R = 10  #int(input("Enter the number of rows:"))
     ...: C = 10 #int(input("Enter the number of columns:"))
     ...: # Initialize matrix
     ...: matrix = []
     ...: print("Enter the entries rowwise:")
     ...:
     ...: # For user input
     ...: for i in range(R):          # A for loop for row entries
     ...:     a =[]
     ...:     for j in range(C):      # A for loop for column entries
     ...:          a.append(0)
     ...:          if i == 4 and j == 3:
     ...:              a.append("/")
     ...:     matrix.append(a)
     ...: #print("/",matrix[index[20]][index[10]])
     ...: #matrix.insert([0][0],'/')
     ...: for i in range(R):
     ...:     for j in range(C):
     ...:         print(matrix[i][j], end = " ")
     ...:     print()
     ...:
Enter the entries rowwise:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 / 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Update:

```
In [180]: R = 10  #int(input("Enter the number of rows:"))
     ...: C = 10 #int(input("Enter the number of columns:"))
     ...: # Initialize matrix
     ...: matrix = []
     ...: print("Enter the entries rowwise:")
     ...:
     ...: # For user input
     ...: for i in range(R):          # A for loop for row entries
     ...:     a =[]
     ...:     for j in range(C):      # A for loop for column entries
     ...:          a.append(0)
     ...:     matrix.append(a)
     ...: matrix[(R//2)-1].insert((C//2)-1, "/")
     ...: #print("/",matrix[index[20]][index[10]])
     ...: #matrix.insert([0][0],'/')
     ...: for i in range(R):
     ...:     for j in range(C):
     ...:         print(matrix[i][j], end = " ")
     ...:     print()
     ...:
Enter the entries rowwise:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 / 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: would be better if i could do this with a ```print``` statement outside the ```for loop```

Comment: @ShubhamBhurke Updated my answer

Comment: @bigbounty why not matrix[4][4] = '/' ??

Comment: It's `matrix[4][4]` only i.e `R//2 -1` and `C//2 - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Not going to lie I copied and modified code from this source here:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/
It explains how to use it and why it works.

```
rows = int(input("Enter row size: "))
cols = int(input("Enter col size: "))
rowPlacement = int(input("What row to place maker: "))
colPlacement = int(input("What col to place maker: "))

arr = [["X" for i in range(cols + 1)] for j in range(rows + 1)] 
arr[rowPlacement][colPlacement] = str("O")
for row in arr: 
    print(row)
```

Comment: It seems like you will not need something bigger then what you might be using it for.